# Force Refresh when Link with Hash Tag is Clicked

Tags: jquery, iframe, hash, reload

I have a page with an iframe and then sidebar links. The sidebar links lead to articles loaded within the iframe. Each sidebar link has a link like this "/news#1940," where the number following the # tag corresponds to the ID of the article. I then am using the following jQuery to both load the news page on our site and then the appropriate article within the iframe.

```
  var $news_story       = $(window.location.hash.substring(1)),
      $news_number      = $news_story.selector,
      $news_url         = 'http://www.articleurlhere.com/ID=' + $news_number,
      $news_url_default = 'http://www.main_news_feed_url_here.com';
      var $url           = location.pathname;

        if ($news_number.length>0) {
          $('#news-feed').attr('src', $news_url);
        } else {
          $('#news-feed').attr('src', $news_url_default);
        }
```

This works great when you click on the sidebar links from an external page. It does not work however when you click on a sidebar link while on the news page (it changes the URL to the #number associated with the link, but does not reload the page or load the article in the iframe). Any ideas on how to make these links work while on the news page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call reload like this:

```
window.frames["news-feed"].location.reload();
```

Comment: his code is loading something based on the fragment, instead of loading just force the load event again and it should pick it up and fire his code no?

Comment: Also, I tried, 
    $('#news-links a').click(function(){
      window.location.reload();
    });
but this simply reloads the page, but no longer changes the URL of the window to correspond with the href of the sidebar link.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing `$(document).trigger('load');`

Comment: Where are you thinking I need to put this reload (regardless of which version I use)? Should I put it within a click state of the sidebar links:  $('#news-links a').click(function(){//reload here });. I think I tried to do this and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using hashes in links...the page wouldn't reload when the hash tag changed. My solution was to switch the hash tag out for a question mark. That caused links ending with '?YourLinkLabel' to actually reload the page each time the link label changed (the change was triggered by clicking on a link whose href attribute ended with '?YourLinkLabel').